# Creating diagrams in Latex Document

Tags: diagrams

I have been reading the Springer Series mathematics books, which are all created on Latex. They have very nice diagrams, and I was wondering how they make them on Latex or what program they use.

Comment: Ask Springer about it?

Comment: `picture` - mode perhaps, with a lot of `\put` statements? Or `pstricks` or `tikz`. That are LaTeX packages for drawing graphs etc.

Comment: Just sent them an email, and thank you @ChristianHupfer any easier alternatives? Ive looked at tikz and that looks real tough to use

Comment: Could you put Springer's answer when you will obtain it, please?

Comment: @MarcoFroelich “Diagram” is very general. Do you mean “commutative diagrams” (as in category theory) or other kinds of diagrams?

Comment: Really nice diagrams usually take some effort to draw/write. The main drawing packages, `tikz` and `pstricks`, take some effort to learn but if you need to draw a complex diagram then you need to learn...something.  You are essentially asking how to draw *all* of the *diagrams* in the Springer books written using LaTeX. I think that this question is impossible to answer and hence too broad and too vague for TeX.SX.

Comment: `pstricks` is probably easier to learn, as it uses a LaTeX syntax, and has small specialised modules with their own documentation. For commutative diagrams, you should take a look at `pst-node` and its `psmatrix` environment. `auto-pst-pdf` allows for a compilation with `pdflatex` (the old way was `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`) if you compile with the `-shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` switch.

Comment: @MarcoFroelich: Well, you could learn some spell at Hogwarts in order to get the work done ;-) Or pay someone to do the job for you ;-)

Comment: They use Geogebra, Asymptote or the Latex Packages